# MySQL Recurring years timestamp query

Tags: mysql, date

I need to send an email out every year that a user has been a member. Here is my original query, which infact is wrong because after the first year it no longer is valid:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE date_format(date_created,'%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 365 DAY = CURRENT_DATE()`

How do I fix this so it can be valid every year that they have been active?

Comment: How do you want to handle leap years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ?

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE DAY(date_format(date_created,'%Y-%m-%d')-CURRENT_DATE()) = 0
AND MONTH(date_format(date_created,'%Y-%m-%d')-CURRENT_DATE()) = 0
```

or better :

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE DAY(date_created)=DAY(CURRENT_DATE())
AND MONTH(date_created)=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Comment: on 1st March, e-mail should be sent to people who registered on 29th Feb as well as to those who registered on 1st March. Current query does not achieve this.

Comment: It should be handled with a special case in the where clause.

Comment: Something general would be better I guess.